# How do I replace a custom AppSetting class with a MultiAppSetting class in ServiceStack?

Tags: c#, .net, servicestack, amazon-dynamodb

We have decided to use the new DynamoDbAppSettings class in our application to take advantage of DynamoDb.  We are currently using a custom class that inherits from AppSettings (part of the class shown below):

```
public class MyAppSettings : AppSettings
{
    public ApplicationEnvironment Environment
    {
        get { return Get("Environment", ApplicationEnvironment.Development); }
    }

    public List<string> AdministratorEmails
    {
        get { return Get("AdminEmailAddresses", new List<string>()); }
    }

    public string CompanyReadConnectionString
    {
        get
        {
            string settingsName = "CompanyReadConnectionString_{0}".Fmt(Environment);
            return Get(settingsName, string.Empty);
        }
    }
 }
```

What I'm not so clear about is how to make the transition to MultiAppSettings.  For example, we currently register our AppSettings like so:

```
//Custom App settings
container.RegisterAutoWired<MyAppSettings>();
MyAppSettings appSettings = container.Resolve<MyAppSettings>();
```

And I can then use the appSettings variable to access my app settings very easily, with all of the defaults, etc. being checked in the custom class, plus the benefit of no "magic strings" scattered throughout my application.  As an example, I can easily get the Debug Mode via:

```
appSettings.DebugMode
```

For DynamoDb, I have added code like what is shown in the examples:

```
MultiAppSettings multiAppSettings = new MultiAppSettings(
      new DynamoDbAppSettings(
      new PocoDynamo(AwsConfig.CreateAmazonDynamoDb()), true),
            new MyAppSettings());
```

But I'm unclear how to work with it at this point.  How do I, or can I, have a custom class like the one shown above that works with MultiAppSettings?  If so, how do I register it and access my app settings?  Is it appropriate to use my existing custom class as the fallback when declaring the MultiAppSetting variable?  Any more pointers on working with DynamoDbAppSettings would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [AWSApps AppHost](https://github.com/ServiceStackApps/AwsApps/blob/e375e2678f13acf8eab8a5028c2beb17891307b8/src/AwsApps/AppHost.cs#L32-L34) shows an example of using `MultiAppSettings` with `DynamoDbAppSettings` by assigning `base.AppSettings` in the AppHost constructor, e.g:

```
public AppHost() : base("AWS Examples", typeof(AppHost).Assembly)
{
#if !DEBUG
    //Deployed RELEASE build uses Config settings in DynamoDb
    AppSettings = new MultiAppSettings(
        new DynamoDbAppSettings(newPocoDynamo(AwsConfig.CreateAmazonDynamoDb()),
            initSchema:true),
        new AppSettings());
#endif
}
```

Which will now replaces `base.AppSettings` provider from just looking at your Web.config's `<appSettings/>` to first look at config in DynamoDB before falling back to Web.config appSettings when a particular entry doesn't exist.

E.g. this is used in `AppHost.Configure()` to [populate API Keys for each registered AuthProvider](https://github.com/ServiceStackApps/AwsApps/blob/e375e2678f13acf8eab8a5028c2beb17891307b8/src/AwsApps/AppHost.cs#L75):

```
return new AuthFeature(() => new AuthUserSession(),
    new IAuthProvider[]
    {
        new CredentialsAuthProvider(),              //HTML User/Pass 
        new BasicAuthProvider(),                    //HTTP Basic Auth
        new DigestAuthProvider(AppSettings),        //HTTP Digest Auth
        new TwitterAuthProvider(AppSettings),       //Twitter
        new FacebookAuthProvider(AppSettings),      //Facebook
        new YahooOpenIdOAuthProvider(AppSettings),  //Yahoo OpenId
        new OpenIdOAuthProvider(AppSettings),       //Custom OpenId
        new GoogleOAuth2Provider(AppSettings),      //Google OAuth2
        new LinkedInOAuth2Provider(AppSettings),    //LinkedIn OAuth2
        new GithubAuthProvider(AppSettings),        //GitHub OAuth Provider
    })
{
    HtmlRedirect = "/awsauth/",
    IncludeRegistrationService = true,
};
```

The `IAppSettings` is automatically registered in Funq so your Services can access it just like any other dependency, e.g:

```
public class MyServices : Service
{
    public IAppSettings AppSettings { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.  In your example above, I would be setting AppSettings to my custom class, based on MultiAppSetttings, i.e., `AppSettings = new MyAppSettings(new DynamoDbAppSettings(new PocoDynamo(AwsConfig.CreateAmazonDynamoDb()), true));`.  While I can then reference AppSettings, the code doesn't know that it is my custom class.  Using `(MyAppSettings)AppSettings.MyProperty` doesn't work.  I could use `var appSettings = AppSettings as MyAppSettings` but it feels awkward.  any suggestions?

Comment: @TortillaCurtain This is just normal C#, the idea behind an `IAppSettings` (or any provider for that matter) is that your class isn't supposed to know about your concrete AppSettings provider so you can later configure the AppSetting sources as you'd like and it still works, so I'd highly discourage casting back to your concrete type, but if you want to continue doing that you can just hide property access behind typed extension methods.

Comment: In my case I have a strongly typed AppSettings class and am trying to not disrupt it or my code.  I was hoping to make this existing class based on `MultiAppSettings` instead of just `AppAettings`.  If I change AppSettings to MultiAppSettings in the declaration, then I'll have to use magic strings to refer to my AppSettings everywhere, whereas now I can just use `appSettings.Property` and I know about any errors during compilation.  I got the wrapper idea from the ServiceStack 4 Cookbook, but is this method now unusable if I'm going the MultiAppSettings route?

Comment: You can wrap magic strings behind typed extension methods or can use a static class with string constants. Exposing a concrete class is obviously bad for substitutability.